# MySQL Mark Records with Duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MYSQL table named customers.   Some of these have duplicate entries on orderNumber.
I'd like to enter the value of DUPL in customers.working in all of these records, not just the extra copy.   Note that the values in fieldA and fieldB may not be duplicates, so I need to mark all.

table customers  (Order number '123 is duplicate)

```
orderNumber     fieldA      fieldB     working
123             vdss        fhghg
456             bhtf        fhbb
789             goyh        vhhgg
123             fhgh        fhfhf
```

desired, after update ()

```
orderNumber     fieldA      fieldB     working
123             vdss        fhghg      DUPL
456             bhtf        fhbb 
789             goyh        vhhgg
123             fhgh        fhfhf      DUPL
```

The select works perfectly:

```
SELECT `orderNumber` 
FROM `customers` 
GROUP BY `orderNumber` 
HAVING COUNT(`orderNumber`) > 1
```

But the update does not.  I have an error that MYSQL cannot use the select to update:

```
UPDATE `customers` set `customers.working` ='DUPL' where `customers.orderNumber` = 
(SELECT `orderNumber` 
FROM `customers` 
GROUP BY `orderNumber` 
HAVING COUNT(`orderNumber`) > 1);
```

I also tried this, but get a syntax error:

```
UPDATE `customers` SET `customers.working` ='DUPL' 
WHERE customers.orderNumber = INNER JOIN 
(SELECT `orderNumber` 
FROM `customers` 
GROUP BY `orderNumber` 
HAVING COUNT(`orderNumber`) > 1);
```

What is the correct way to format this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is from memory and not tested. As you have not said what the error was, I am making a guess from doing similar before with Mysql. If the error is saying you cannot update and select from the same table, you need to add an alias to the select. If not, I think you should use an IN, not a join.

Not tested but should work

```
UPDATE `customers`
SET    `customers.working` = 'DUPL'
WHERE  customers.ordernumber IN (SELECT t1.`ordernumber`
                                 FROM   (SELECT ordernumber
                                         FROM   `customers`
                                         GROUP  BY `ordernumber`
                                         HAVING Count(`ordernumber`) > 1) AS t1);
```

On a mobile so hopefully formatted ok and brackets in the correct order etc :)

Comment: This returns  #1054 - Unknown column 'customers.working' in 'field list' (Although it does exist in the table)

Comment: Check the back ticks around the update clause if you pasted from here as 2 are missing :)

Comment: Yes, I saw the backticks before loading - With a small change I made this work:  removed references to table name "customers.orderNumber and customer.working" and simply used orderNumber and working.  (I'm not sure why this was a problem).

Comment: @Kevin - great stuff, glad it worked and I could help from memory on a mobile. Can you mark this as the accepted answer?

Answer (score 1):

You use of `JOIN` statement is invalid. Try this:

```
UPDATE `customers` c
       INNER JOIN (SELECT `ordernumber`
                   FROM   `customers`
                   GROUP  BY `ordernumber`
                   HAVING Count(`ordernumber`) > 1) jn
               ON jn.ordernumber = c.ordernumber
SET    c.working = 'DUPL'
```

Comment: `jn` is an alias for result of `SELECT` inside `JOIN`.

Comment: This returns :#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INNER JOIN (SELECT `orderNumber` FROM `customers` GROUP BY `orderNumber` ' at line 2

Comment: Ups, fix my answer. `SET` shoul be after `JOIN`.  Check it

Comment: This returns  #1054 - Unknown column 'customers.working' in 'field list' (Although it does exist in the table)

Comment: OK.  I add alias for customers table too