# MySQL Markup Records with Duplicates on Select

Tags: mysql

I have seen [MySQL Mark Records with Duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710216/mysql-mark-records-with-duplicates) question and answers. But I have a different situation.

How to select all records, but have a flag for those records who have duplicates in a given field.

```
id     name 
--------------
1      John 
2      Peter 
3      John 
4      David
```

And I want something like that:

```
SELECT 
    id,
    name,
  -- IF(~duplicate in name~, 1, 0) AS is_duplicate
FROM tab
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume id is set to auto increment then you can use following query for your desired output

```
select distinct a.*,
case when b.id is null then 0 else 1 end `duplicate`
from tab a
left join tab b 
on a.name = b.name
and a.id > b.id
order by a.id
```

[Demo](http://rextester.com/ICXEN38950)

Comment: @vatavale using above approach no you can't , i guess you can ask new question i will try for that criteria

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728899/mysql-markup-records-with-duplicated-values-first-one-in-group-included-withou

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid how is that not possible? All you need is `a.id <> b.id`

Comment: @PaulSpiegel I wasn't sure with that approach, however your proposed solution looks fine to me but i haven't thought about that