# MySQL Markup all records on Select with same values (first one included)

Tags: mysql

Connected with [MySQL Markup Records with Duplicates on Select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47728233/mysql-markup-records-with-duplicates-on-select). The difference is I want to markup not only actually duplicated records but **all** records with same values **including first one**.

```
id     name 
--------------
1      John    # mark this
2      Peter 
3      John    # this
4      David 
5      John    # and this
```

The approach proposed by @m-khalid-junaid https://stackoverflow.com/a/47728321/1056384

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.*,
CASE WHEN b.id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 end `duplicate`
FROM tab a
LEFT JOIN tab b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id > b.id
ORDER BY a.id
```

It has one or two problems for me:

1. It not markups first occurrence of "duplicate" record in group.
2. It uses `order by` **id** (not sure if it depends) but I need to sort result in real complex query by different ways.

If it makes sense for query optimization, my task is a little bit more complex. Actually, I need to markup duplicates inside groups only:

```
id   group  name
--------------
1    1      John    # mark this (dups in group #1)
2    1      Peter 
3    1      John    # mark this (dups in group #1)
4    2      David 
5    2      John    # this is not (it's in group #2)
```

Comment: 1. You just need to change `>` to `<>`. 2. You can use what ever you need in the ORDER BY clause. But without specifying it, no one can help you.

Comment: Wow. It's realy works. But could you explain the logic behind it? How with <> record from b-table is joining on same id?

Comment: Its joining on **not same** id. `<>` is *not equal*. You can also use `!=`.

Comment: `WHEN b.id IS NULL` its **not** a duplicate, because no match has been found with the same name but a different id.

Answer (score 1):

While you can adjust the given query to your needs, I would use an EXISTS subquery here instead of a join.

```
select t.id, t.group, t.name, exists (
  select * from tab t2
  where t2.group = t.group
    and t2.name  = t.name
    and t2.id <> t.id
) as is_duplicate
from tab t
order by t.group, is_duplicate, t.name
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d24012/4

Comment: Thank you. Is it faster than `LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t.name = t2.name AND t.group = t2.group AND t.id <> t2.id`

Comment: @vatavale Note that you should define an index on `(group, name)` or `(group, name, id)` for both queries. You might also want to try this one: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d24012/9

Answer (score 1):

Looks like this works for me:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*,
       IF(t2.id IS NULL, 0, 1) AS is_duplicate
FROM tab t
LEFT JOIN tab t2 ON t.name = t2.name AND t.group = t2.group AND t.id <> t2.id
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d24012/16/0